# C# web form listbox OnSelectedIndexChanged

Tags: c#, webforms

I have a listbox on my website, which contains some elements.

I made the event, OnSelectedIndexChanged, so when the user presses an element, this value will be put into a textbox

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    listbox = new Listbox();

    // Add to page etc.

    listbox.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(listbox_SelectedIndexChanged);

}

void listbox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        textbox_name.Text = listbox.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }
    catch
    {
        textbox_info.Text = "Choose employee";
    }
}
```

It works in c# windows forms, but not in web forms for some reason.

Is it possible to get it to work?

Thank you

Comment: Set autopostback property of the listbox  true

Comment: And don't put that to Page_Load, because it get's executed on every postback. Use the aspx-file instead.

Comment: you can put it there but check for IsPostback property on load event :)

Comment: I put in listbox.AutoPostBack = true; which made it work. Thanks. Is there anything else I should be aware of?

Comment: as UNeverNo said put your listbox in aspx file and link the event from there

Comment: But is there any consequences having it in cs file and in page_load ? Because it seems to work as intended right now

Comment: it is not really an issue, but try to avoid it..designer is there for your controls...btw have posted that as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set autopostback property of the listbox true